# Issue with IE9+ and Flip Card

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have this unique feature for a client where on click of one div another div flips in it's place, think of it like a card, like how some people have those portfolio image flippers. Difference is it flips divs with content inside vs images.

**How can I add IE support to it since it uses the preserve-3d animation?**

See a live example here:

[Live card](http://www.creatotech.com/did-you-know/)

Code:

```js
$(".cc").click(function(){$(this).toggleClass("active")});
```

```css
.cc {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    height: 325px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -ms-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -o-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}

.c {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.cc.active .c {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.face.front {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #800605;
}

.face.front h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}

.face.back {
    display: block;
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #057F80;
}

.face.back p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cc">
<div class="c">
<div class="front face">
<h2> Fact 1 </h2>
</div>
<div class="back face">
<p> “Drinking cold water can help lower your temperature back to normal while in high heat or strong sun, when you’re at risk of heat exhaustion, heat stroke, and/or death. In addition, cold water is absorbed more quickly into your body than warm water, expediting rehydration according to Columbia University” (McAllister, 2013). </p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit: I've fixed support for IE10 + in my answer below. However I am done fiddling with this for IE9, that bloody thing is nothing but a death contraption. If someone else can fix it for IE9 that's be great, otherwise this question can be considered solved by the answer I posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you mean when you say that you added "support" for it. Internet explorer just doesn't support this type of animation.

Comment: Is there a way to add support for it?

Comment: I dont _believe_ so. Internet-explorer is completely out of date and has lost alot of functionality, especially when it comes to using things like CSS3

Answer (score -1):

After much rewriting and testing I finally found a solution, albeit it's nowhere near the original code.

Live example:
[Click here](http://www.creatotech.com/did-you-know/)

Fiddle: [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/anL6bsuL/2/)

Code:

```js
        function() {
            function n(n) {
                n.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    var n = this.classList;
                    n.contains("flipped") === !0 ? n.remove("flipped") : n.add("flipped")
                })
            }
            for (var o = document.querySelectorAll(".c.click"), e = 0, i = o.length; i > e; e++) {
                var l = o[e];
                n(l)
            }
        }();
```

```css
.c {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    color: #fff;
}

.cb,.cf {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}

.cf {
    background-color: #800605;
}

.cb {
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.cf h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 100px 20px;
}

.cb p {
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 100px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.c.click.flipped .cf {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.c.click.flipped .cb {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
    transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c click">
   <div class="cf">
       <h2> Fact 1 </h2>
   </div>
   <div class="cb">
          <p> Internet Explorer needs to just die off already. </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in IE9, it just shows the back and clicking it does nothing.

Comment: Okay so IE9 doesn't support the classList attribute. I've tired everything under my guise from poly-filling the attribute with another script to switching it to .hasClass. If someone else figures out how to fix it for IE9 then that'd be great, otherwise IE10+ will have to do at this point.